# Oracle Sqlplus connection using sys dba

Tags: oracle

After installation of oracle 21c i using alien on my Ubuntu 23.10.1 i didn't get any prompt during installation process to set a password por sys user and now i can't log into database as sys as sysdba or as system (/).
Plese tell me what to do to set the password for sys user during installation process.

Comment: It never does afaik You need to run the root.sh script with sudo. You connect with your own user and password and then make a db/user/pwd inside oracle